# hash function in C

Tags: c, hash

I need to create some hashing function... can you help me?

The input is a sequence of numbers. Your task is to determine the number of how many numbers are repeated.

Its string of numbers and letters (***a[]**). **N** is the number of digits -input.

Returns the number of repetition.

```
int function(char *a[], int n)
{
  int i,j;
  int same=0;

  for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
  {
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
      if(!strcmp(a[i],a[j]))
        same++;
    }
  }

  return same;
}

int main(void)
{
  char *a[] = {"AA123456", "BA987689", "AA123123", "AA312312", "BB345345", "AA123123"};
  printf("Number of duplicates: %d\n", function(a, 6));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Smells like homework, and you haven't proposed any solutions. -1. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: y i need to change my function i created, it has to be hash... and i dont know how to change it

Comment: @Tiestik: follow all the links and references I gave you...

Answer (score 1):

Read the wikipage on [hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) & [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Often, a linear combination with prime coefficients (see [bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity))  and involving the components and the partial hash gives good enough result.

For example, something like

```
int basile_hash(const char*str) {
   int h = 65537;
   while (*str) {
      h = 75553*h + 5531* (*str);
      str++;
   };
   return h;
}
```

I don't claim it is a very good hash, but it is probably good enough for your needs. All the constants 65537, 75553, 5531 are primes (given by `/usr/games/primes` from `bsdgames` Debian package)

You could make a variant with bitwise xor `^`, or you could take into account more than one component:

```
  h = 65579*str[0] ^ 5507*str[1] + 17*h;
  str += 2;
```

but you should care -and special-case when `s[1]` is the terminating null byte.

Read also about [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)

Notice that a lot of standard or popular libraries gives you many hash functions. Most of the time the particular choice of some hash function is not very important. On the other hand, you can still earn a PhD on studying and inventing good hash functions. I have another one in this [values.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/blob/master/values.c) file, function `mom_cstring_hash` near line 150 (I imagine that it might be better optimized, since for large strings some of the instructions might run "in parallel" inside the processor).

<sup>I certainly don't claim to be expert on hash functions.</sup>

Study also the source code of hash functions in free software libraries like [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/), [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), etc.... See also [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/)